# Postgres connection access denied on IPv6 address

Tags: postgresql, authentication, postgresql-9.1

Installed PostgreSQL 9.1 x64 on Windows, set up a listen address, but when connecting with pgAdmin I get the following error. Not sure why PostgreSQL is seeing my IPv6 address and not my regular IP address:

[image]

To get authentication working, based on the error message, I updated `pg_hba.conf` with this:

`host    all         all fe80::c5d2:XXXX:XXXX:3bc0/12          trust`

That worked, but it's ugly, and too specific. I tried the following based on PostgreSQL docs, but none worked, I get the same 'access denied' error:

```
local all all trust
host all all 0.0.0.0/12 trust
```

I got this one working, which covers the entire IPv6 address space, but how can I specify an IPv6 range for more restriction?

```
host  mydb  myuser  ::/0   trust
```

## **Questions**

- Why does pgAdmin pick up my IPv6 address and not my normal IP?
- How do I specify a range in IPv6 without resorting to `::/0`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The IPv6 addresses starting with `fe80:` are link-local addresses. They cannot be routed across different subnets or the internet. They are for communication between machines connected to the same LAN only. The link-local range is defined as `fe80::/10`. If you trust everybody on your local LAN then you could do

```
host  all  all  fe80::/10  trust
```

If you don't trust everybody on your local LAN then you probably want to use username+password protection:

```
host  all  all  fe80::/10  md5
```

When specifying `md5` you are still using username+password protection, but the password is not transmitted in a readable format anymore. Since you're not trusting people on your local LAN you probably shouldn't send a snoopable password over the wire either.

Comment: `fe80` as the prefix worked, thx. What is the significance of `/12`, `/24`, etc., on the IPv4 address?

Comment: It is the number of bits that is 'fixed' in the address. So `10.0.0.0/16` would mean that the first 16 bits are fixed and the last 16 bits can be anything. So `10.0.0.0` to `10.0.255.255`. `10.0.0.0/24` would be `10.0.0.0` to `10.0.0.255`. And `10.0.0.0/18` would be `10.0.0.0` to `10.0.63.255`, `10.0.64.0/18` would be `10.0.64.0` to `10.0.127.255`, etc.

Comment: And the same goes for IPv6 addresses. `fe80::/10` means `fe80:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000` to `febf:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff`. Google on "CIDR notation" for more info.

Comment: PS: I have no clue what `0.0.0.0/12` is supposed to do. It would be the range `0.0.0.0` to `0.15.255.255`, all of which is reserved address space according to http://www.iana.org/assignments/ipv4-address-space/. Those addresses should never appear in any real connection.

Answer (score 3):

IPv6 is used because you are connecting to `localhost`. `localhost` resolves to *both* `127.0.0.1` and `::1`.

Because operating systems prefer IPv6 over IPv4, that is the reason why IPv6 is used (although on Linux, this can be configured through `/etc/gai.conf`). The address `::1` is never used as a source address, and you don’t have a global address (`2000::/3`), which leaves the link-local address (`fe80::/10`) as the source address.

All perfectly logical, normal, expected behaviour when you think about it.

Comment: If it were logical to me, I wouldn't have asked the question in the first place, lol, but thx for the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

I am not quite sure why pgAdmin has the behavior it does.  My recommendation there would be to ask on their support lists and get info on the design of that tool and whether this is a bug or a feature.  It may have also to do with Windows name resolution.  As a workaround you should be able to specify connecting over the ipv4 address or to 127.0.0.1.

As for the pg_hba.conf question, ipv4 and ipv6 get the different spaces in the file so it doesn't surprise me that you would have to add this.

One option you have, now that you can connect, is to set a password (`ALTER USER "username" WITH PASSWORD 'password'`).  You can then set your entire ipv6 space to md5 in the pg_hba.conf and not have to worry so much.  Also if you are on a windows domain, you can use LDAP, SSPI, or Kerberos 5 authentication and thus allow access only to domain members.  This is somewhat an advanced topic though.